# Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan().ReadOnly() does not work

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Could any one check this property and its mapping and explain to me why it fires this error.

**Note**
When I comment `.ReadOnly()` it does not fire this error and the same if I change the Cascade Role from `AllDeleteOrphan()` To `All()`

**Here is my code**

```
public virtual IList<ApprovalApplicationTask> Tasks { get; protected set; }

HasMany(entity => entity.Tasks).KeyColumn("APPLICATION_ID").Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
    .ReadOnly().Inverse();
```

**This is the error I get**

> NHibernate.AssertionFailure: no collection snapshot for orphan delete
>   at NHibernate.Engine.CollectionEntry.GetOrphans(String entityName,
>   IPersistentCollection collection) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.DeleteOrphans(String entityName,
>   IPersistentCollection pc) at
>   NHibernate.Engine.Cascade.CascadeCollectionElements(Object parent,
>   Object child, CollectionType collectionType, CascadeStyle style, IType
>   elemType, Object anything, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled) at

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to combine two incompatible settings.

Fluent `ReadOnly` for collections is indeed `mutable="false"` in actual NHibernate mappings. This option declare the collection as immutable. For having orphans to be deleted, you need first to orphan them, which means removing them from the collection, which means mutating it.